# What does scope mean in routes.rb in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, scope, routes

In the code below `scope` is used (in `routes.rb`):

```
scope 'admin' do
  get 'dashboard', to: 'administration#dashboard'
  resources 'employees'
end
```

When and why `scope` is used?

Comment: You should check [*controller-namespaces and routing*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use it when you want to add a prefix for urls:

```
# adds '/dashboard
get 'dashboard', to: 'administration#dashboard'

# adds /admin/dashboard pointing to the same action
scope '/admin' do
  get 'dashboard', to: 'administration#dashboard'
end
```

It has more options. See [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)